# Character in email body if value empty

Tags: php, html, post

I have an iPad app that sends data to a PHP page using a post with body method and this works fine. On receiving this data the PHP page sends a notification email with some of the information from the body.

For one user I am getting this:

[image]

For some reason the for this user the app does not send the id or email and the body string looks like:

```
id=&posted_by=admin&email=
```

The reason for no id or email obviously needs to be fixed but in the meantime I am trying to catch this occurrence in the php page using:

```
if ($_POST['id'] == '' OR $_POST['id'] === NULL) {
   .... do something...
}
```

However, this does not work. What would the value of `$_POST['id']` be if its value had not been included in the body?

Comment: Are you sure this is a `$_POST`? This looks like a `$_GET`

Comment: You should try $_REQUEST['id'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `$_POST['id']` will be a warning `unset` variable `id` when it does not set in the body.

Before getting the value of `$_POST['id']` you should use `isset()` function as:

```
if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])){
  // do something
}else{
  // else part
}
```

**Note:** If you have no idea which type of method used to send data then you should use `$_REQUEST['id']`, it works for both `GET` and `POST` methods.